# how to convert .pts or .npy file into .ply or .h5 file?

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, ply-file-format

I have 3d point cloud data as .npy file and .pts data.

To use these data for 3d classification neural net, I have to change these data to .h5 file.

So, first I am trying to convert .npy or .pts file to .ply file using python.

Could you refer to me example codes  or help me for converting file format?

Also, I will really appreciate for ways to  convert .ply to .h5 format..

Sorry for my poor english skills.

Comment: I'm thinking, can you load the weights into a keras model? If you can, you can  then save the weights from there

Comment: @DanielR. Thx for reply, but what I'm trying to do is just convert .npy or .pts format to .ply or .h5 format..

Comment: I asked because [this](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) is very simple to do with keras, and it outputs in h5/hdf5 format

Comment: @DanielR. I'm thinking that you are talking about saving model as h5/hdf5 format, because you mentioned 'weights' right? But I have 3d point cloud data (x,y,z) as .npy and .pts format.. And I want to change those..

Comment: You are right, my bad, I just read the words neural network and .h5 and drew the wrong interpretation.

Comment: You'll have to use `numpy` to load the .npy files, and `h5py` to write those arrays to .h5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this code will get you started, it shows how to create a h5 file from a npy (or random points). Warning the name of group and dataset are arbitrary (it's an example).

```
import os
import h5py
import numpy as np

# reading or creating an array of points numpy style
def create_or_load_random_points_npy(file_radix, size, min, max):
    if os.path.exists(file_radix+'.npy'):
        arr = np.load(file_radix+'.npy')
    else:
        arr = np.random.uniform(min, max, (size,3))
        np.save(file_radix, arr)
    return arr


# converting a numpy array (size,3) to a h5 file with two groups representng two way
# of serializing points
def convert_array_2_shades_of_grey(file_radix, arr):
    file = h5py.File(file_radix + '.h5', 'w')
    #only one dataset in a group
    group = file.create_group("single_dataset")
    group.attrs["desc"]=np.string_("random points in a single dataset")
    dset=group.create_dataset("points", (len(arr), len(arr[0])), h5py.h5t.NATIVE_DOUBLE)
    dset[...]=arr
    #create a dataset for each coordinate
    group = file.create_group("several_datasets")
    group.attrs["desc"] = np.string_("random points in a several coordinates (one for each coord)")
    dset = group.create_dataset("x", (len(arr),), h5py.h5t.NATIVE_DOUBLE)
    dset[...] = arr[:, 0]
    dset = group.create_dataset("y", (len(arr),), h5py.h5t.NATIVE_DOUBLE)
    dset[...] = arr[:, 1]
    dset = group.create_dataset("z", (len(arr),), h5py.h5t.NATIVE_DOUBLE)
    dset[...] = arr[:, 2]

# loads the h5 file, choose which way of storing you would like to deserialize
def load_random_points_h5(file_radix, single=True):
    file = h5py.File(file_radix + '.h5', 'r')
    if single:
        group = file["single_dataset"]
        print 'reading -> ', group.attrs["desc"]
        dset=group["points"]
        arr = dset[...]
    else:
        group = file["several_datasets"]
        print 'reading -> ', group.attrs["desc"]
        dset = group["x"]
        arr = np.zeros((dset.size, 3))
        arr[:, 0] = dset[...]
        dset = group["y"]
        arr[:, 1] = dset[...]
        dset = group["z"]
        arr[:, 2] = dset[...]
    return arr

# And now we test !!!
file_radix = 'test'
# create or load the npy file
arr =  create_or_load_random_points_npy(file_radix, 10000, -100.0, 100.0)
# Well, well, what is in the box ?
print arr

# converting numpy array to h5
convert_array_2_shades_of_grey(file_radix, arr)

# loading single dataset style.
arr = load_random_points_h5(file_radix, True)
# Well, well, what is in the box ?
print arr
# loading several dataset style.
arr = load_random_points_h5(file_radix, False)
# Well, well, what is in the box ?
print arr
```

To view the content of the h5 file, download [HDFview](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdfview/).

[image: h5 file content]

Also don't hesitate to look at the [h5py doc](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/).

And last but not least, you can always ask question to the HDF5 community at [HDFgroup forum](https://forum.hdfgroup.org/t/quickstart-guide-welcome-to-the-new-hdf-forum/27) (they deliver shiny badges like SO, waouh !!!)

Answer (score 1):

*Correction/Improvement of [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52340306/13093413)*

If you have multiple .npy files that you want to transform into .h5 then write the path of the directory they're in into the variable `NPY_DIRECTORY`:

```py
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import os
import h5py
import numpy as np
NPY_FILES_DIRECTORY = ""
filenames = [f for f in listdir(NPY_FILES_DIRECTORY) if isfile(join(NPY_FILES_DIRECTORY, f))]



# reading or creating an array of points numpy style
def create_or_load_random_points_npy(filename, size, min, max):
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        arr = np.load(filename)
    else:
        arr = np.random.uniform(min, max, (size,3))
        np.save(filename, arr)
    return arr


# converting a numpy array (size,3) to a h5 file with two groups representng two way
# of serializing points
def convert_array_2_shades_of_grey(filename, arr):
    file = h5py.File(filename + '.h5', 'w')
    #only one dataset in a group
    group = file.create_group("single_dataset")
    group.attrs["desc"]=np.string_("random points in a single dataset")
    dset=group.create_dataset("points", (len(arr), len(arr[0])), h5py.h5t.NATIVE_DOUBLE)
    dset[...]=arr
    #create a dataset for each coordinate
    group = file.create_group("several_datasets")
    group.attrs["desc"] = np.string_("random points in a several coordinates (one for each coord)")
    dset = group.create_dataset("x", (len(arr),), h5py.h5t.NATIVE_DOUBLE)
    dset[...] = arr[:, 0]
    dset = group.create_dataset("y", (len(arr),), h5py.h5t.NATIVE_DOUBLE)
    dset[...] = arr[:, 1]
    dset = group.create_dataset("z", (len(arr),), h5py.h5t.NATIVE_DOUBLE)
    dset[...] = arr[:, 2]

# loads the h5 file, choose which way of storing you would like to deserialize
def load_random_points_h5(filename, single=True):
    file = h5py.File(filename + '.h5', 'r')
    if single:
        group = file["single_dataset"]
        print('reading -> ', group.attrs["desc"])
        dset=group["points"]
        arr = dset[...]
    else:
        group = file["several_datasets"]
        print('reading -> ', group.attrs["desc"])
        dset = group["x"]
        arr = np.zeros((dset.size, 3))
        arr[:, 0] = dset[...]
        dset = group["y"]
        arr[:, 1] = dset[...]
        dset = group["z"]
        arr[:, 2] = dset[...]
    return arr

# And now we test !!!
for filename in filenames:
    # create or load the npy file
    arr = create_or_load_random_points_npy(filename, 10000, -100.0, 100.0)
    # Well, well, what is in the box ?
    print(arr)

    # converting numpy array to h5
    convert_array_2_shades_of_grey(filename, arr)

    # loading single dataset style.
    arr = load_random_points_h5(filename, True)
    # Well, well, what is in the box ?
    print(arr)
    # loading several dataset style.
    arr = load_random_points_h5(filename, False)
    # Well, well, what is in the box ?
    print(arr)
```