# convert point cloud .npy file to .h5 in python

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, point-clouds

I asked similar question before ([how to convert .pts or .npy file into .ply or .h5 file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52326888/how-to-convert-pts-or-npy-file-into-ply-or-h5-file/52340306#52340306)).

But I have more advanced question.

[h5format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey1xW.png)

as shown in above picture, this .h5 file has (N,N,3) shape.

and I have point cloud data as (N,3) shape .npy file format.

The way I convert .npy to .h5 as former question's answer(above link)

The result .h5 shows (N,3) shape.(as below picture)

[converted_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYesj.png)

Could you refer to me example codes or help me for converting file format?

Sorry for my poor English skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I got the solution from many other example codes.

```
for i in range(0, len(filenames)):
    if filenames[i] == "":
        continue        
    npydata = np.load("./data/npy/" + filenames[i] + ".npy")

    print(npydata.shape)

    for j in range(0, 2048):
        a_data[i, j] = [npydata[j][0], npydata[j][1], npydata[j][2]]

data = f.create_dataset("data", data = a_data)
f.close()
```

The above code solved my problem.